# SWrevealviewcontroller should be visible on welcome screen after login

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am new to iOS ran into a problem, I have successfully implemented `SWRevealViewController` side menu and it works if I put the view controller as initial screen but when it comes to showing it after login procedure it does not show up the menu, so after searching the web for quite some time I found out that I need to design a separate story board for login and register and separate for other screens.. so I did it as per that. Still, I have problems in showing up my side menu. My code does not get in

```
if revealViewController() != nil{ }
```

It returns `NULL` so the code does not go ahead.

[image]

And this is my second storyboard:

[image]

I am using `UserDefaults` to keep whether the user is logged in or not and storing user profile details in `UserDefaults` as well to be used within the app for future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use second storyboard.

You can simply switch between `UIViewController`s by implementing a container view controller, if not using `segue`s for specific reasons.

However, what I would suggest is to set your main view controller, `revealViewController`?, as an initial view controller, and check login status (using your `UserDefaults`) on `viewDidLoad()`. If there's no available login info, modally present another view controller for the login process. Then simply dismiss the login view controller if login succeeded.

Comment: you mean i shall add login check code in viewcontroller or app delegate ?

Comment: @Swan In the view controller since you may have to present login view controller at this moment.

Comment: thank you very much you have really helped me, i have removed another storyboard and now app is working just fine as planned..

Comment: @Swan glad to help you.

Comment: sorry to bother you but can you help me with this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039567/camera-and-gallery-image-upload-by-alamofire-in-swift-3