# Camera and gallery image upload by alamofire in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, alamofire

Hi there i have spent more than 20 hours to figure out how to upload image from my app to server, image which i want to upload could be either taken from camera or photo roll..... here is my code which does show progress of uploading but doesnt reach to server and thus gets negative response form server.. please help me..

```
  Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!, withName: imageName)
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        },
                         to: URL_USER_PROFILE_IMG_UPLOAD)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.result.value)
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
```

and my server code is in PHP as this

```
    <?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "profile-photos/";

// array for final json respone
$image_upload = array();
 $server_ip ="00.000.000.000";
//gethostbyname(gethostname());
// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip .'/'.'folder2017'.'    /'.'webser'.'/'. $target_path;



if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
$target_path=$target_path.$_FILES['image']['name'];
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path))         {
        $image_upload=array('path'=>$file_upload_url,'response_code'=>1);
        echo json_encode($image_upload);
  }
  } else {

  $image_upload=array('response_code'=>0);
  echo json_encode($image_upload);
  }



?>
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out instantly just by looking at this code. If this is not working as you expect, You'll first have to find where the real problem is: the server? or the client? Test your server by using 3rd party tools and see if the server responses as you planned. If it does, the problem is in your client side codes.

Comment: hi friend, my server code is working fine since its the same code being used for android version and it does upload image as desired, i get progress information in log but after completion it throws response 0. i am lost in this, any clue will really be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace

```
multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)!, withName: imageName)
```

With

```
let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)!
multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
```

Comment: Hi akash thank you for taking a time , i have figured out my mistake and already fixed it but i do appreciate that you have rightly answered it... thanks have a great day ahead...